# PHP UML class diagram

Tags: php, uml

Is there anyone who has a good (basic) UML class diagram to get me started on an object oriented CMS?

I want to start using OOP in PHP but can't seem to find a good starting point.

Comment: If I might suggest, learn OOP design first and than consider using UML for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can read some UML basics.
And here are some examples of [UML and PHP](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/PHP-and-UML-Class-Diagrams/530)

Hope it helps..